# Почему не применяются стили для блоков через querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Объясните пожалуйста, почему во время применения querySelectorAll стили не задаются для блоков? но если задать querySelector, то нужный стиль применяется для нужного блока.

Логика такая: по нажатию на button должен появляться блок. По умолчанию у блоков стоит display: none, по нажатию на button должно меняться на display: Block

```js
let showMsg = document.querySelectorAll('.msg-1 .msg-2 .msg-3');


function viewMsg() {
    showMsg.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.msg-1 {
    display: none;
}

.msg-2 {
    display: none;
}

.msg-3 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-ui">
    <div class="chat-items">
        <div class="msg">
            <p>первый этап</p>
            <button value="Click" onmousedown="viewMsg()">далее</button>
        </div>
        <div class="msg msg-1">
            <p>второй этап</p>
            <button value="Click" onmousedown="viewMsg()">далее</button>
        </div>
        <div class="msg msg-2">
            <p>конец</p>
            <button value="Click" onmousedown="viewMsg()">отправить</button>
        </div>
        <div class="msg msg-3">
            <p>полный конец</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Потому -   `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')",`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) возвращает `NodeList` (массив), в свою очередь [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает `Element` (один элемент).

Для применения стилей ко всем элементам из `NodeList` необходимо сделать обход циклом и назначить свойство каждому элементу:

```
for (let i = 0; i < showMsg.length; i++) {
   let msg = showMsg[i];
   msg.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Чего методом не перебрал?

Comment: @WalkMess циклом нагляднее и эффективнее. И достала эта функциональщина в JS на самом деле.

Comment: @WalkMess Помимо наглядности в контексте работы с DOM у NodeList есть метод forEach, а у HTMLCollection, который возвращает, например, Document.getElementsByClassName уже такого метода нет и для новичка это может быть проблемой, так что лучше показать сначала примитивные циклы.

Comment: @Slavik, но ведь и NodeList и HTMLCollection могут быть легко преобразованы в массив с помощью Array.of() или просто [...document.querySelectorAll('')]. И тогда уже сортировать, фильтровать, перебирать и так далее)))

Comment: @Leonid ну тут выбор: либо ответить человеку, который вероятнее всего новичок, так, как будет работать в его примере, и, зная, что в будущем он может споткнуться, предупредить его об этом и еще больше запутать, либо дать я бы сказал классическое и более надежное решение в качестве примера, где ни о чем больше предупреждать не нужно; я выбрал второе

Comment: @Slavik, так говорите как будто мы генераторную функцию Symbol.iterator для прототипов коллекций вручную определяем. Метод Array.of для того и ввели чтобы можно было привести разнообразные коллекции, включая строки, к базовой структуре данных - к массивам. В конце концов, надо еще объяснить откуда берется свойство .length у этих коллекций и строк. А так с помощью короткого синтаксиса мы получаем знакомые нам массивы и все, куда проще то...

Comment: спасибо большое за объяснение

Comment: @Leonid ты можешь оставить свой ответ на вопрос и всё в нем пояснить, у людей, кто попадет сюда, например, из поисковика, будет выбор, какое решение им подходит/нравится

Comment: @Slavik, все правильно вы говорите)) Я плюсы вам поставил и с решениями согласен, не принимайте за критику или еще что. Просто хотел понять глубинные, так сказать, мотивы. Может я просто не вижу чего... А существенно добавлять здесь нечего, вопрос банальный, и два варианта уже есть)) Вы здесь совершенно правы, добавили свой ответ с уникальным подходом и вложили свое видение.

Answer (score 3):

У вас две ошибки. Во-первых, вы неправильно написали selector:
`.msg-1 .msg-2 .msg-3`. В таком виде ничего не найдет, так как будет искать `.msg-3` внутри `.msg-2` внутри `.msg-1`.

Во-вторых, `querySelectorAll` возвращает коллекцию элементов. Можно применить стили для каждого элемента по отдельности

```js
let showMsg = document.querySelectorAll('.msg-1, .msg-2, .msg-3');


function viewMsg() {
    showMsg.forEach(el => el.style.display = 'block');
}
```

```css
.msg-1 {
    display: none;
}

.msg-2 {
    display: none;
}

.msg-3 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-ui">
    <div class="chat-items">
        <div class="msg">
            <p>первый этап</p>
            <button value="Click" onmousedown="viewMsg()">далее</button>
        </div>
        <div class="msg msg-1">
            <p>второй этап</p>
            <button value="Click" onmousedown="viewMsg()">далее</button>
        </div>
        <div class="msg msg-2">
            <p>конец</p>
            <button value="Click" onmousedown="viewMsg()">отправить</button>
        </div>
        <div class="msg msg-3">
            <p>полный конец</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо что указали на ошибки и объяснили